# Show first item of DropDown/ListBox automatically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the dropdown values as 1 to 50. 35 is the selected item. So while clicking this, 35 is the default option as opened. I want the listbox automatically scroll to the top and show the first item .

i.e
Now the default listbox displayed as

[image: Now the default listbox displayed as]

But i want the display as

[image: the scroll moves up and shows the first option]

Is there any possibility in Jquery. Please do the needful. Thanks

Comment: With regular dropdowns, no, you don't have that kind of control over them. You can roll your own dropdowns to get this behavior.

Comment: Agree with Marc. Not with regular dropdowns but you can look at something like http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If anybody found the solution for this, please convey to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but some starting point for you.

```
var originalValue, isScrolled = false,
isChanged = false,
isFirstClick = false;
$(document).click(function(e) {
   var id = e.target.id;
   if (id == "") id = $(e.target).parent().attr("id");
   if (id != "drop" && (isFirstClick == true)) {
       isFirstClick = false;
       $("#drop").val(originalValue)
   }
});
$("#drop").click(function(e) {
   isFirstClick = !isFirstClick;
   if (isChanged == true) {
       isFirstClick = false;
       isChanged = false;
       return;
   }
   originalValue = $(this).val();
   $(this).val(1);
}).change(function(e) {
   isChanged = true;
});​
```

Demo on jsFiddle.net : http://jsfiddle.net/g6bVJ/4/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. It is working. But  i have the following problem. I click the list box and selects nothing. Then again i click the list box i does not scroll to top. If i click the list box and select some value, then it works fine. To fix this where to change the code.

Comment: You were right, it was not working FF. Updated the code : http://jsfiddle.net/g6bVJ/4/